# Retrieving a value by searching for the key in firebase, using swift

Tags: swift, firebase, search

How can I get the value of a key by searching for that key in firebase, using swift. 
Say, having the following structure, I want to retrieve userName3 as String, by searching for userID3?

```
users-used
    userID1 : userName1
    userID2 : userName2
    userID3 : userName3
    userID4 : userName4
```

Comment: Did you try something atleast ?

Comment: snapshot.value(forKey: userName3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the 'users-used' directory is at the root of the structure you should be able to it in the following way:

```
Database.database().reference().child("users-used").child("userID3").observeSingleEvent(of: .value)  { (snapshot) in
        guard let username = snapshot.value as? String else {
            return
        }
        // username will be available here as a string if successful
    }
```

Keep in mind that everything in the closure will be run asynchronously and can return at any time